# Why does the int and uint comparison fails in one case but not in another?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider following program:

```
static void Main (string[] args) {
    int i;
    uint ui;

    i = -1;
    Console.WriteLine (i == 0xFFFFFFFF ? "Matches" : "Doesn't match");

    i = -1;
    ui = (uint)i;
    Console.WriteLine (ui == 0xFFFFFFFF ? "Matches" : "Doesn't match");

    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

The output of above program is:

```
Doesn't match
Matches
```

Why the first comparison fails when unchecked conversion of integer -1 to unsigned integer is 0xFFFFFFFF? (While the second one passes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first comparison will be based on longs ... since 0xFFFFFFFF is not an int value :)
Try to write

```
Console.WriteLine( (long)i == 0xFFFFFFFF ? "Matches" : "Doesn't match" );
```

and you will get a `cast is redundant` message

Comment: No, 0xFFFFFFFF is a uint value... just try that : `0xFFFFFFFF.GetType().Name`

Comment: @Thomas: ok, you are right. The point is: it's not in int ... edited

Comment: There is a compiler warning on the i == 0xFFFFFFFF saying "Comparison to integral value is useless; the constant is outside the range of int". So what @tanascius said.

Comment: I don't receive any warning when I compile the program posted in question. My warning level is set to 4. Am I missing something? (Using VS 2008, .NET 3.5)

Answer (score 2):

In the second case you cast -1 into uint, getting 0xFFFFFFFF, so it matches as expected. In the first case apparently the comparison is done in a format with suitable range for both values, allowing for the mathematically correct result that they do not match.